# Hive ignore nulls

Tags: sql, hive, analytic-functions

I am trying to rewrite `last value(col1 ignore nulls )` analytical function in hive from RDMS.

I used `select last_value(col1,TRUE)`

But I am getting null as output when used for above query.
Can someone please suggest is there any other way to ignore nulls in analytic function in hive.

Answer (score 1):

The default comparison method of the `OVER()` function is to compare the current row with all previous rows. You need to add a sentence after the `order by` statement: `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`:

```
last_value(col1,TRUE) over (partition by col1 order by col2 rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```