# Generate new column based on other columns and previous row value

Tags: sql, hive, relational-database, hiveql

I have a table for employees where I have running total of sales by every employee in each of the 12 months. Some of the values for sales running total are missing, as below:

| e_id | month | sales_run_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | Jan | 10 |
| e1 | Feb | null |
| e1 | March | null |
| e1 | April | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| e1 | Dec | 120 |
| e2 | Jan | null |
| e2 | Feb | null |
| e2 | March | 30 |
| e2 | April | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| e2 | Dec | 120 |

I want to impute these missing values with the previous month's sales_run_total value of an employee.
If the missing value is for January month, I want to impute it with zero, as below:

| e_id | month | sales_run_total | sales_run_total_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | Jan | 10 | 10 |
| e1 | Feb | null | 10 |
| e1 | March | null | 10 |
| e1 | April | 40 | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| e1 | Dec | 120 | 120 |
| e2 | Jan | null | 0 |
| e2 | Feb | null | 0 |
| e2 | March | 30 | 30 |
| e2 | April | 40 | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| e2 | Dec | 120 | 120 |

I have tried to do it using lag() function, as below :

```sql
select e_id,
       month,
       lag(sales_run_total) over (partition by e_id, month) as sales_run_total_new
from table_name
```

But this does not consider whether there is a null or non-null value in actual column. Also, it does not consider the case where we have null for January month.

How can this be done in SQL?

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173864/hive-ignore-nulls

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick the window between proceedings and current row and find most recent not null value.
Use  `LAST_VALUE (value, ignore_null boolean)` window function to pick last non null value ordering by e id and month.
`LAG()` isnt suitable because it can not reach beyond previous row and you can have null value in previous row.

can you pls try this ?

```
SELECT e_id,`month`,sales_run_total,
COALESCE(sales_run_total, LAST_VALUE(sales_run_total, TRUE) OVER(ORDER BY e_id, `month` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))  as sales_run_total_new
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Thanks @Koushik. I solved it in 2 steps:
First, whenever the month is January and the sales value is NULL, I imputed it with 0.
Then, I used the approach suggested by you to get the final table.

Comment: First step to do before the solution in answer:
SELECT e_id, `month`, sales_run_total,
case when sales_run_total is NULL then (
    case when service_month = 'Jan' then 0 else sales_run_total end 
) else sales_run_total 
end as sales_run_total_temp
FROM table_name